# Razor read text file to memory from input type text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

trying to read text into memory from a text file the user selects

MODEL:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

VIEW

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyForm">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
                 <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="ProcessAll" value="Process All" />
            </form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileToFasta(F2FModel model)
{
//Need to read file to a string without uploading it
return View(model);
}
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new StreamReader(model.File.InputStream).ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.IO namespace.

```
var sw = new StreamReader(model.File.InputStream);
var text = sw.ReadToEnd();
sw.Close();
```